# Factory selector does not fire subscription with state update

Tags: ngrx

Referencing [this NGRX ticket](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2980), I am seeing an oddity where a code-based subscription to a factory selector does not fire with state updates, however, the `async` pipe *does* work.

To clarify, if I set up a public observable property on a component and bind the HTML to it with an `async` pipe, the value will update as the state updates.

component.ts

```
public test$: Observable<ChatInteraction>;
[...]
this.test$ = this.store
      .select(getNewMessageForChat(this.chat.chatId));
```

component.html

```
test: {{(test$ | async).message}}
```

Then I end up with output like

```
test: test1
test: test2
etc etc
```

However, if I try to subscribe to that same observable, it fires once when the subscription is created, but never again as the state updates.

component.ts

```
this.store
      .select(getNewMessageForChat(this.chat.chatId))
      .subscribe(() => {
        if (this._calculateScrollDistanceFromBottom(this.chatWindowElem.nativeElement) <= 20) {
          this._scrollToBottom();
        }
      });
```

If I put a breakpoint on that `if` statement, it does not get hit as I update state.

Any ideas why?

Comment: That should not be the case, could you create a reproduction of this?

Comment: I figured it out. I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Turned out I had an undefined object reference in my subscription, which caused the subscription to break on its first run and resulted in it no longer firing.  This was difficult to catch as it turns out the `subscription` code has a try/crush in it unless a setting is set.

```
__tryOrUnsub(fn, value) {
        try {
            fn.call(this._context, value);
        }
        catch (err) {
            this.unsubscribe();
            if (config.useDeprecatedSynchronousErrorHandling) {
                throw err;
            }
            else {
                hostReportError(err);
            }
        }
    }
```

`hostReportError` didn't bubble anything up so to me it looked like it just wasn't firing anymore.